# fs2.Stream hangs on taking twice

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect, fs2

**Problem:**

I want to repeatedly take some batches from the `fs2.Stream` provided by some third-party library and therefore abstract clients away from the `fs2.Stream` itself and give them simply `F[List[Int]]` batches as soon as they are ready.

**Attempts:**
I tried to use `fs2.Stream::take` and ran some examples.

**I.**

```
implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)

val r = for {
  queue <- fs2.concurrent.Queue.unbounded[IO, Int]
  stream = queue.dequeue
  _ <- fs2.Stream.range(0, 1000).covaryAll[IO, Int].evalTap(queue.enqueue1).compile.drain
  _ <- stream.take(10).compile.toList.flatTap(lst => IO(println(lst))).iterateWhile(_.nonEmpty)
} yield ()

r.unsafeRunSync()
```

It prints the very first batch `List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)` and then hangs. I expected that all the batches from `0` to `1000` will be printed.

Keeping things a bit simpler here is

**II.**

```
implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)

val r = for {
  queue <- fs2.concurrent.Queue.unbounded[IO, Int]
  stream = queue.dequeue
  _ <- fs2.Stream.range(0, 1000).covaryAll[IO, Int].evalTap(queue.enqueue1).compile.drain
  _ <- stream.take(10).compile.toList.flatTap(lst => IO(println(lst)))
  _ <- stream.take(20).compile.toList.flatTap(lst => IO(println(lst)))
} yield ()

r.unsafeRunSync()
```

The behavior is completely the same to **I**. Prints `List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)` and then hangs.

**Question:**

Given an `fs2.Stream[IO, Int]` how to provide an effect `IO[List[Int]]` which iterates through consecutive batches provided by the stream when evaluated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can not have an `IO[List[X]]` that represents multiple batches, that `IO` would be a single batch.

The best you can do is something like this:

```scala
def processByBatches(process: List[Int] => IO[Unit]): IO[Unit]
```

That is, your users will give you an operation to execute for each batch and you would give them an `IO` that will block the current fiber until the whole stream was consumed using that function.

And the simples way to implement such function would be:

```scala
def processByBatches(process: List[Int] => IO[Unit]): IO[Unit] =
  getStreamFromThirdParty
    .chunkN(n = ChunkSize)
    .evalMap(chunk => process(chunk.toList))
    .compile
    .drain
```